# Does mylar interfere with magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

Say you have a magnet, and you completely cover it with mylar. What happens to the magnetic field? Are the field lines altered? Is the strength of the magnetic field outside the mylar covering lessened?

How about if you wrap a solenoid (electromagnet) with mylar?

Comment: Mylar's just a film of polysester, so it really wouldn't alter a magnetic field in a measurable way. Foiled mylar (mylar with a metal film which is what I think you meant) would also not affect a magnetic field in a noticable way. For a time-varying magnetic field however, there would be an effect, as the metal foil will affect (and effect lol!) the consequent electric fields.

Answer (score -1):

As the vast majority of organic materials and molecules mylar is diamagnetic. It was the substrate of choice for magnetic tapes and is often use as substrates in a wild range of experiments / measurements involving electrical optical and magnetic phenomena. Tough it can be commercially come layered with metal, as Aluminum for instance. I do not know how much the paramagnetismus of it can interfere in your case. Just take bare mylar (PET, short for polyethylene terephthalate).

Comment: I would appreciate a comment to elucidate why this deserves a downvote. It would be beneficial to future readers as well.